# Blazor website not displaying tailwind css hover effects

Tags: c#, css, .net, blazor, tailwind-css

I making a new site in C# Blazor.

I have a column of buttons that i want to change colour when you hover over them.
Simple enough i assumed and did this

`hover:bg-blue-500'

However it does not work at all. I get no hover for changing colour of shadows.

```
<section class="grid absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 right-2">
<ul class="grid grid-rows-5 gap-2">
    <li>
        <button class="outline outline-1 outline-black rounded-lg p-1 hover:bg-main-colour hover:shadow-xl bg-white w-[35px] h-[35px]">
            T
        </button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="outline outline-1 outline-black rounded-lg p-1 bg-white w-[35px] h-[35px] hover:bg-main-colour">
            T
        </button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="outline outline-1 outline-black rounded-lg p-1 bg-white w-[35px] h-[35px] hover:bg-main-colour">
            T
        </button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="outline outline-1 outline-black rounded-lg p-1 bg-white w-[35px] h-[35px] hover:bg-main-colour">
            T
        </button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="outline outline-1 outline-black rounded-lg p-1 bg-white w-[35px] h-[35px] hover:bg-main-colour">
            T
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Does any know how to fix this?
Im using a preprogrammed colour called main-colour but its the same process.
I have also tried adding the tailwind to the

tag, no effect...however the shadow does work on this?

Answer (score 0):

turns out blazor doesnt like 'bg-white' i had to change it to 'bg-[#fffff]'

Comment: Blazor doesn't care about "bg-white", that's a CSS thing. Blazor will happily output the "bg-white" CSS attribute and let the browser render it as it will. My guess is that maybe the project still has a reference to the default Bootstrap .css file and that the Bootstrap "bg-white" is conflicting with the Tailwind "bg-white".